# Show that $HK\cong H\times K$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H\lhd G$ and $K\lhd G$ s.t. $H\cap K=\{1\}$. Show that $$HK\cong H\times K.$$

**Attempts**

Using second isomorphism theorem, we have that $HK/K\cong H$ and $HK/H\cong K$, so I need to prove that $$HK\cong HK/K\times HK/H.$$

To simplify notatino let $W=HK$. I consider the group morphism $$W\longrightarrow W/H\times W/K$$
defined by $$w\longmapsto (wH,wK).$$
The injectivity is clear, but I have problem to show surjectivity. Could someone help ?

Comment: By the definition of $HK$, every element of $HK$ is a product of the form $hk$ with $h \in H$ and $k \in K$. Conversely, every such product is contained in $HK$. Given that $H$ is normal in $G$, both left and right classes are the same, so try writing $Hw$ instead of $wH$.

Comment: Or you could also try an explicit homomorphism $hk \mapsto (h, k)$. Because $H\cap K = \{1\}$, it is properly defined, as every element of $HK$ is uniquely written in the form $hk$. To show that it is a homomorphism, notice that both $H$ and $K$ centralize each other (expand a product $hkh'k'$ in two different ways).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $h\in H$ and $k\in K$, $hk=kh$. Indeed,
$$
hkh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H\cap K
$$
because both $H$ and $K$ are normal, so $hkh^{-1}\in K$ and $kh^{-1}k^{-1}\in H$.

Thus $H\times K\to HK$ defined by $(h,k)\mapsto hk$ is a well defined group homomorphism. It is obviously surjective. What's its kernel?

Comment: Nice answer, tks